# What Type Of Encoding Is This?

Tags: encoding

I need help, what type of encoding is this?
It is a popular encoding, not an encryption.

```````````
begin 666 Restricted.zip  
M4$L#!!0````(`%T[="_]<LYX`P(``'0#```.````4F5S=')I8W1E9"YT>'1M
M4\MNVT`0NQOP/TSNM@PT0!/X4N16`RE0%.GC.I9&TE;2CKH/J_K[<E;IX]"+
M'UJ20W)6^]U3)SX=]KO][D*]SD(7XHD2CX/S'26EU`L%U_6)9@E1?46NQ4,7
MR?E6P\3)J:=%@ABZY7'$P2MO"0J1GGT3Z;B1YJ#?I4ZT:!X;N@KI34)%3Y%6
MS8#>A#I-&[;E`-H%'(EY@G[/(-I',=GI;XN"H49?''YXT#LE]BNU.<!&,*(W
M0&4Y7V#,F_&11NV<-TNU-!D!>HZP5"MF91^YE0-D&H2C5CAL\T&P:#/'A*<+
M#F6(!IEXW?Q?13Q=@P[XLBHJ>L[UX,;U8+`"X3I)0S^RJX=Q+3-28)@@+IK:
MEAD@AQRM7DY)ICG%BK[:(,\=L$C>20*EUCR/8BP'&'H+.OT5:+`V>,*NK$%9
MZ<;>Q1X"1WJOBZ#_8HQ+`3?K%(U<1U-:7.HI6A]_+/V[\RU,J]DW!SMV@<37
M89W+>5QCL6/"MDHTQPV&UT5-<R!=?%D)MG^AR&Y3^>]::JP0H2MZ4>3UR?F,
M[>18,L'"..I2K'.,BP8TF<K)YT_/IG1S#<@VZ^,KX$QO'[\\WC_<W;V[?_-P
MW>^`/%.?TGP^G99EJ29MCC^K6JL\G%H78CJQC[CGU=S/V_M2KEN<A0?;A5U`
M[AC.U2*6OUOE0<KD#Q#\MM_]`E!+`0(4`!0````(`%T[="_]<LYX`P(``'0#
M```.``````````$`(`"V@0````!297-T<FEC=&5D+G1X=%!+!08``````0`!
+`#P````O`@``````
`
end
```````````

Please tell me what type this is, or decode it for me. Thank you, all.

Comment: Umm... Some kind of compression that adheres to the zip file container?  What does this have to do with security? Voting to close.

Comment: The file is from a zip file. This text was in a text file, within the ZIP. The text file is named, Restricted.zip.

Comment: ... and what does that have to do with security?

Comment: Hint: `uudecode`

Answer (score 6):

After decoding the file, I can see it's from a mod-x.co.uk challenge. You should ask for help on their forums or figure it out yourself.